# What's the best way to handle a REST API's 'create' response in Backbone.js

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js to interact with a REST API that, when posting to it to create a new resource, responds with a status of 201, a 'Location' header pointing to the resource's URI, but an empty body.

When I create a new model at the moment, its successful, but the local representation of the model only contains the properties I explicitly set, not any of the properties that would be set on the server (created_date, etc.)

From what I understand, Backbone would update its representation of the model with data in the body, if there were any.  But, since there isn't, it doesn't.

So, clearly, I need to use the location in the Location header to update the model, but what's the best way to do this.

My current mindset is that I would have to parse the url from the header, split out the id, set the id for the model, then tell the model to fetch().

This seems really messy.  Is there a cleaner way to do it?

I have some influence over the API.  Is the best solution to try to get the API author to return the new model as the body of the response (keeping the 201 and the location header as well)?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be of some help: https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie/blob/master/backbone_tastypie/static/js/backbone-tastypie.js#L15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you will have to do a little customization.
Perhaps override the parse method and url method of your model class inherited from
Backbone.Model.

The inherited functions are:

```
url : function() {
  var base = getUrl(this.collection);
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
},
parse : function(resp) {
  return resp;
},
```

and you could try something like:

```
parse: function(resp, xhr) {
    this._url = xhr.getResponseHeader('location')
    return resp
}
url: function() {
    return this._url
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of handling this in the Parse method.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, backbone.js really wants the result of a save (be it PUT or POST) to be a parseable body which can be used to update the model.  If, as you say, you have influence over the API, you should see if you can arrange for the content body to contain the resource attributes.

As you point out, its makes little sense to make a second over-the-wire call to fully materialize the model.

It may be that a status code of 200 is more appropriate.  Purists may believe that a 201 status code implies only a location is returned and not the entity.  Clearly, that doesn't make sense in this case.

Answer (score 2):

With Backbone 0.9.9, I couldn't get the accepted answer to work. The signature of the `parse` function seems to have changed in an older version, and the `xhr` object is no longer available in the function signature.

This is an example of what I did, to make it work with Backbone v0.9.9 and jQuery 1.8.3 (using a [Deferred Object/Promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)), relying on the [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) returned by [`Backbone.Model.save()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) :

```
window.CompanyView = Backbone.View.extend({
// ... omitted other functions...

    // Invoked on a form submit
    createCompany: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Store a reference to the model for use in the promise
        var model = this.model;
        // Backbone.Model.save returns a jqXHR object
        var xhr = model.save();
        xhr.done(function(resp, status, xhr) {
            if (!model.get("id") && status == "success" && xhr.status == 201) {
                var location = xhr.getResponseHeader("location");
                if (location) {
                    // The REST API sends back a Location header of format http://foo/rest/companys/id
                    // Split and obtain the last fragment
                    var fragments = location.split("/");
                    var id = fragments[fragments.length - 1];
                    // Set the id attribute of the Backbone model. This also updates the id property
                    model.set("id", id);
                    app.navigate('companys/' + model.id, {trigger: true});
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I did not use the `success` callback that could be specified in the `options` hash provided to the `Backbone.Model.save` function, since that callback is invoked before the XHR response is received. That is, it is pointless to store a reference to the `jqXHR` object and use it in the `success` callback, since the `jqXHR` would not contain any response headers (yet) when the callback is invoked.

Another other to solve this would be to write a custom `Backbone.sync` implementation, but I didn't prefer this approach.